# Run Airflow task at separate time from the rest of the DAG's tasks

Tags: airflow

I have an Airflow DAG that runs once daily at a specific time. The DAG runs a bunch of SQL scripts to create and load tables in a database, and the very last task updates permissions so that users can access the tables. Currently the permissions task requires that all previous SQL tasks have completed, so this means that none of the tables' permissions are updated if *any* of the table tasks fail.

To fix this I'd like to create another permissions task (i.e., a backup task) that runs at a preset time regardless of the status of any of the previous tasks (doesn't hurt to update permissions multiple times). If I don't specify a time different from the DAG's time, then because the new task has no dependencies, the task will try updating permissions before any of the tables have been updated. Is there a setting for me to pass a cron string to a specific task? Or is there an option to pass a timedelta on top of the task's DAG time? I need to run the task some amount of time after the DAG time.

Answer (score 0):

If your permissions task can run no matter what the result of the upstream tasks, I think the best option is simply to change the `trigger_rule` of your permissions task to `all_done` ([default is `all_success`](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.models.BaseOperator)).

If you need to do some specific stuffs when there is a failure, you could consider creating a secondary DAG which first step is a sensor that waits for the main DAG to complete with State.FAILED, then run your permissions task.

Have a look at [ExternalTaskSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.sensors.external_task_sensor.ExternalTaskSensor) when you want to establish a dependency between DAGs.

I haven't checked but you might also need to use `soft_fail` on the sensor to prevent the secondary DAG to show up as failed when the main DAG completes successfully.